# Memcache Not Working with Symfony (Memcached is installed)

Tags: php, symfony, memcached

I have memcached installed on a new Mac using Pecl. When I type Telnet localhost 11211 I get something back. Further, Memcached appears in my php info page as well.

However, when I view my symfony project I get an error saying that "You must have memcache installed and enabled to use sfMemcacheCache class." What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different extensions for using memcache in php: [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.memcache.php) and [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.memcached.php). Most likely you installed the wrong extension. Just install the other one as well and all should be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much, Pierre, for the help! This totally fixed it! Much appreciated.